# caseTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively update itself?

Tags: apex

```
public class CaseOwnershipAssignment{

    public static void CaseOwner(List<Case> caselist){
   list<id> caseid = New list<id>();
   list<case> caseOwnerid = New list<case>();
   list<case> finalcase = New list<case>();

for(Case record: caselist) {
     caseid.add(record.id);
 }
   for(case record: [SELECT id,type,Account.type,priority,OwnerId from case WHERE id IN :caseid]) {
   caseOwnerid.add(record);
   }
     for(Case record: caseOwnerid) {

    IF((record.Priority == 'High' && ((record.Account.Type =='Prospect' || record.Account.Type =='Installation Partner'|| record.Account.Type =='Customer - Direct') 
          && (record.type == 'Electrical' || record.type == 'Structural'))) || (record.Priority =='Low' 
          &&((record.Account.Type =='Prospect' || record.Account.Type =='Installation Partner' || record.Account.Type =='Customer - Direct') && 
               (record.type == 'Mechanical' || record.type == 'Electronic')))){

               record.OwnerId = System.Label.RohanD;
               finalcase.add(record);
               system.debug('+++++++++++record.OwnerId1'+record.OwnerId);

               }else IF((record.Priority == 'Low' && ((record.Account.Type =='Prospect' || record.Account.Type =='Installation Partner'|| record.Account.Type =='Customer - Direct') 
          && (record.type == 'Electrical' || record.type == 'Structural'))) || (record.Priority =='High' 
          &&((record.Account.Type =='Prospect' || record.Account.Type =='Installation Partner' || record.Account.Type =='Customer - Direct') && 
               (record.type == 'Mechanical' || record.type == 'Electronic')))){

               record.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
               finalcase.add(record);
               system.debug('+++++++++++record.OwnerId2'+record.OwnerId);

               }

}

update finalcase;
  }

 }
```

Trigger:

```
Trigger caseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) {
  if(Trigger.isBefore){
          if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                  CaseOwnershipAssignment.CaseOwner(Trigger.new);
          }
          if(Trigger.isInsert){
                     //Code to execute before insert
          }
  }
  else if (Trigger.isAfter){
          if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                    //Code to execute after update
          }
          if(Trigger.isInsert){
                  //Code to execute after insert
          }
   }
}
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error:Apex trigger caseTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: caseTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 5006F000027U5uSQAS; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 5006F000027U5uS) is currently in trigger caseTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []: Class.CaseOwnershipAssignment.CaseOwner: line 33, column 1
```

Can anyone please help me why this error coming and what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to query the account records and update the values in caselist directly. Any changes made in a before-insert/before-update trigger will automatically be applied without a DML operation.

---

```
public class CaseOwnershipAssignment{
    public static void CaseOwner(List<Case> caselist){
        Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Case record: caseList) {
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, null);
        }
        accounts.putAll([SELECT Type FROM Account WHERE Id = :accounts.keySet()]);

        for(Case record: caselist) {
            String accountType = record.AccountId != null? accounts.get(record.AccountId).Type: null;
            IF((record.Priority == 'High' && ((accountType =='Prospect' || accountType =='Installation Partner'|| accountType =='Customer - Direct') 
                && (record.type == 'Electrical' || record.type == 'Structural'))) || (record.Priority =='Low' 
                &&((accountType =='Prospect' || accountType =='Installation Partner' || accountType =='Customer - Direct') && 
                    (record.type == 'Mechanical' || record.type == 'Electronic')))){
                    record.OwnerId = System.Label.RohanD;
                    system.debug('+++++++++++record.OwnerId1'+record.OwnerId);

                    }else IF((record.Priority == 'Low' && ((accountType =='Prospect' || accountType =='Installation Partner'|| accountType =='Customer - Direct') 
                && (record.type == 'Electrical' || record.type == 'Structural'))) || (record.Priority =='High' 
                &&((accountType =='Prospect' || accountType =='Installation Partner' || accountType =='Customer - Direct') && 
                    (record.type == 'Mechanical' || record.type == 'Electronic')))){
                    record.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    system.debug('+++++++++++record.OwnerId2'+record.OwnerId);
            }

            }

    }

}
```